# pacman - get list of packages installed by user

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

How can I get a list of packages that were explicitly installed by a user?

I'm aware of:

```
pacman -Qe
pacman -Qi
```

But those seem to include the default packages for my distribution (e.g. sudo). I want to list only the packages that were installed by a user using e.g. "pacman -Syu newpackage"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Arch Linux doesn't really have a set of default packages, though if you install from the guide you likely installed the `base` package group, and possibly `base-devel`. You can use `comm` to filter these (I'm assuming `bash` here):

```
comm -23 <(pacman -Qqett | sort) <(pacman -Qqg base-devel | sort | uniq)
```

You can use `Qqe` instead of `Qqett` if you want to include explicitly-installed packages that are also dependencies of some other package.

Comment: This worked well! So just to clarify, pacman also doesn't keep track of who installs something?

Comment: @pandita On my system, attempts to install software as non-root yields `error: you cannot perform this operation unless you are root.` If you use `sudo`, you become root. So as far as `pacman` can tell, the only user who can install a package is root and there's no need to track that

Comment: Try `comm -23 <(pacman -Qqett | sort | uniq) <(pacman -Qqg base -g base-devel | sort | uniq)` So they are both in the same sorted order

Comment: This has a problem with circular dependencies. For example, jupyter is required by X which is required by Y .... which is required by jupyter. So although I explicitly installed it and it won't be installed as a dependency of any listed package, jupyter itself is not listed, which makes the output of this command unable to ensure reproducibility.

Comment: This answer is no longer working as now base is not a group, but a meta-package.

Comment: @RahatZaman I believe you just have to remove the `base` package from the query: `comm -23 <(pacman -Qqett | sort | uniq) <(pacman -Qqg base-devel | sort | uniq)` its now working for me and the output appears to make more sense.

Answer (score 3):

simpler solution, that keeps historical order:

```
grep -i installed /var/log/pacman.log
```

however you will have upgrades in this list, and it will not contain explicitly installed only

Answer (score 1):

alternate option that will include AUR

```
# packages installés explicitements - la base - les foreign
pacman -Qqe | grep -vx "$(pacman -Qqg base-devel)" | grep -vx "$(pacman -Qqm)" > main.lst

## Create local.lst of local (includes AUR) packages installed
# que les foreign
pacman -Qqm > aurandlocal.lst
```